# How to add numbers in tikz (for use in labels)

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode

This code works great (place bit labels b0, b1, ..., b7 in boxes), but now I want to do the same thing right below it with b8, b9, ..., b15. Is there any way to add 8 to the index `\k` for use in a label?

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc}
\def\d{0.55cm} 
\tikzset{
  >=latex,
  mybox/.style={rectangle, very thin, draw, outer sep=0, minimum width = \d, minimum height = \d, inner sep=0}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \k in {0,...,7} {
    \node[mybox] at (-\k*\d, 0) {$b_{\k}$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In essence, I would like to do this:

```
\foreach \k in {0,...,7} {
    \node[mybox] at (-\k*\d, 0) {$b_{\k}$};
    \node[mybox] at (-\k*\d, \2*d) {$b_{somehow add 8 to \k}$};
    \node[mybox] at (-\k*\d, \4*d) {$b_{somehow add 16 to \k}$};
    \node[mybox] at (-\k*\d, \6*d) {$b_{somehow add 24 to \k}$};
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using two nested `\foreach` loops and the option `evaluate` to get the number for the node text:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc}
\def\d{0.55cm} 
\tikzset{
  >=latex,
  mybox/.style={rectangle, very thin, draw, outer sep=0pt, minimum size = \d, inner sep=0pt}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,3}{
  \foreach[evaluate={\j=int(\k+\i*8)}] \k in {0,...,7} {
    \node[mybox] at (-\k*\d, 2*\i*\d) {$b_{\j}$};
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with an empty `matrix`. `matrix` parameters are total size and row length.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\def\d{0.55cm} 
\tikzset{
    mybox/.style={rectangle, 
        very thin, 
        draw, 
        outer sep=0pt, 
        minimum size = \d, 
        inner sep=0pt},
    mymatrix/.style 2 args={matrix of nodes,
        very thin,
        nodes in empty cells,
        nodes={mybox, anchor=center, 
            node contents = $b_{\the\numexpr#1-#2*(\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-1)-\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn\relax}$},
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        row sep = \d},
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[mymatrix={32}{8}] {
 &&&&&&&\\
 &&&&&&&\\
 &&&&&&&\\
 &&&&&&&\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but that's not what i'm trying to do; I want to place nodes at specific x,y locations

Comment: @JasonS I didn't understand your question like this. In any case, with a `matrix` you can fix relative position of nodes with `column sep` and `row sep`.